# Swap img src, ahref src for gallery. Javascript//Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a real struggle.

This is for a webshop. I have a "Big image" and a few thumb images. When I click the big image I want to open a lightbox gallery with my other images.

What I'm also trying to do is that when I press a thumb image I want to swap place and link with the big image. So that the thumb that is pressed becomes the big image and the big image becomes the thumb image.

I've been trying for hours and don't seem to get it to work.

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div id="gallery" style="max-width: 400px;">

    <div class="image">
        <a href="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-600x600.jpg" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" class="zoomThis" data-lightbox="bilder">
            <img src="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-388x388.jpg" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" id="main-img" width="388" height="388">
        </a>
    </div>


    <ul>
        <li id="1" style="float: left;">
            <a href="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-03-600x600.jpg" class="thumb-link-1" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder"></a>
            <img src="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-03-74x74.jpg" class="thumb-img-1" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74">

        </li>

        <li id="2" style="float: left;">
            <a href="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-02-600x600.jpg" class="thumb-link-2" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder"></a>
            <img src="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-02-74x74.jpg" class="thumb-img-2" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74">

        </li>

        <li id="3" style="float: left;">
            <a href="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-04-600x600.jpg" class="thumb-link-3" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder"></a>
            <img src="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-04-74x74.jpg" class="thumb-img-3" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74">

        </li>

        <li id="4" style="float: left;">
            <a href="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-05-600x600.jpg" class="thumb-link-4" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder"></a>
            <img src="http://image/cache/data/50RO160-05-74x74.jpg" class="thumb-img-4" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74">

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript I've worked with so far (and alot of others) but I can't get it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#gallery li").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //Getting the ID of the LI that is pressed
    var oldBIGIMG = $("#main-img").attr('src'); //Getting the OLD big img link
    var oldBIGLINK = $(".zoomThis").attr('href'); //Getting the OLD big ahref
    var newBIGIMG = $(".thumb-img-" + id).attr('src'); //Getting the OLD thumb img
    var newBIGLINK = $(".thumb-link-" + id).attr('href'); //Getting the OLD link

    $("#main-img").attr('src',newBIGIMG.replace('74x74', '600x600')); //Makeing the OLD thumb img BIG by replaceing 74x74 with 600x600 and adds the "newBIGIMG" value to to #main-img's src
    $(".zoomThis").attr('href',newBIGLINK);  //Giveing the old THUMB link to the big LINK (So correct image opens on lightbox press)
    $(".thumb-img-" + id).attr('src',oldBIGIMG); //Makeing the old big image to take the thumbs place
    $(".thumb-link-" + id).attr('href',oldBIGLINK); //Makeing the olg big link to take the thumbs link place

});

</script>
```

If I make every variable hardcoded, like var oldBIGIMG("I type the link"); it seems to work pretty ok. So I guess I'm missing something or doing something wrong.

Anyone that could help me in correct direction would be really great.

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Nothing what I can find with Chrome and Web developer -> Console.

Comment: Its hard to see the problem if we dont have the full code,

Try to replace those lines:
 var newBIGIMG = $(this).child("img").attr('src'); //Getting the New thumb img
    var newBIGLINK = $(this).child("a").attr('href'); //Getting the New link

and also these lines:

$(this).child("img").attr('src', oldBIGIMG); //Makeing the old big image to take the thumbs place
    $(this).child("a").attr('href', oldBIGLINK); //Makeing the olg big link to take the thumbs link place

Comment: Now I get error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...)child is not a function

On this line: var newBIGIMG = $(this).child("img").attr('src');

Comment: What full code are you thinking of, this is kinda all of the code regarding this. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out it might work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("ul li").each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
               var a=$(this).children("a").attr("href");
               $(".image a img").attr("src",a);
            });
          });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: When should this be used, this wont accomplish whats needed if I'm correct? Then it must be together with some other line of codes?

Comment: Kindly let me know exactly what you want i have just made it based on your requirement given. Refer fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/zggmLopr/1/

Comment: This takes me abit on the way and its what I've acomplished before.

Basicly what your code does is that it takes my thumbs <a href> and but it as img src as big one.  Its correct.

But this is what I'm trying to get:

When I click a thumb image, I want the "old big image" to swap place with it. Swap, ahref & img src.  Why?  Because people should be able to preview the thumb image on the spot where the big picture was. But also be able to press the old big image (that is a thumb now) and get it back.

They all are also a lightbox gallery, so its important that the hrefs is correct also.

Comment: So that the current big picture is the one that opens. Sorry if I explain bad but I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function LoadIframeSrc(elemID) {
           
   $('.areffer').each(function(){
    
    if(elemID==$(this).attr('id')){
     
     var mainSrc = $('#main-img').closest("img").attr('src');
     
     $('#main-img').closest("img").attr('src',$(this).find('.imager').attr('src'));
     $(this).find('.imager').attr('src', mainSrc);
    }
   });
   
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery" style="max-width: 400px;">

<div class="image" name="myTarget">
<a href="#" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" class="zoomThis" data-lightbox="bilder">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBDs29Z9gJa8eMnmBVK4ziKc3L325HppfJFBEzpHlzBMGKDHu4" class="imager"  title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" id="main-img" width="388" height="388">
</a>
</div>


<ul>
<li id="1" style="float: left;">
<a href="#" onclick="LoadIframeSrc(this.id)"  class="thumb-link-1 areffer" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder" id="arefTh1">
<img src="http://cdn.filipekberg.se/fekberg-blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/VS2013Logo.png" class="thumb-img-1 imager" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74"></a>

</li>

<li id="2" style="float: left;">
<a href="#" onclick="LoadIframeSrc(this.id)" class="thumb-link-2 areffer" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder" id="arefTh2">
<img src="https://redhoop.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/c_sharp.png" class="thumb-img-2 imager" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74"></a>

</li>

<li id="3" style="float: left;">
<a href="#" onclick="LoadIframeSrc(this.id)" class="thumb-link-4 areffer" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder" id="arefTh3">
<img src="https://university.xamarin.com/images/topic-icons/csharp.png" class="thumb-img-3 imager" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74"></a>

</li>

<li id="4" style="float: left;">
<a href="#" onclick="LoadIframeSrc(this.id)" class="thumb-link-4 areffer" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder" id="arefTh4" >
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiFG_7WJ3lSIX3bZ0VqgOavhox1X5CIRc40BJ34C9r9zscCtzd" class="thumb-img-4 imager" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74"></a>

</li>


</ul>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>


</div>
```

Rgds :)

Comment: Hello and thanks for the help, but I've managed this image swapping before, the problem is to manage to swap images just like you do but make the <a> link also swap. (Key part to get it to work with lightbox like needed) :/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function LoadIframeSrc(elemID) {
           
   $('.areffer').each(function(){
    
    if(elemID==$(this).attr('id')){
     
     var mainSrc = $('#main-img').closest("img").attr('src');
     var newSrc = $(this).find('.imager').attr('src');
     
     $('#main-img').closest("img").attr('src',newSrc);
     $(this).find('.imager').attr('src', mainSrc);
     
     $('#main-href').attr('href', newSrc);
     $(this).attr('href',  mainSrc);
     
    }
   });
   
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery" style="max-width: 400px;">

<div class="image" name="myTarget">
<a href="#" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" class="zoomThis" data-lightbox="bilder" id="main-href">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBDs29Z9gJa8eMnmBVK4ziKc3L325HppfJFBEzpHlzBMGKDHu4" class="imager"  title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" id="main-img" width="388" height="388">
</a>
</div>


<ul>
<li id="1" style="float: left;">
<a href="http://cdn.filipekberg.se/fekberg-blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/VS2013Logo.png" target="myIfOne" onclick="LoadIframeSrc(this.id)"  class="thumb-link-1 areffer" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder" id="arefTh1">
<img src="http://cdn.filipekberg.se/fekberg-blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/VS2013Logo.png" class="thumb-img-1 imager" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74"></a>

</li>

<li id="2" style="float: left;">
<a href="https://redhoop.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/c_sharp.png" target="myIfOne" onclick="LoadIframeSrc(this.id)" class="thumb-link-2 areffer" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder" id="arefTh2">
<img src="https://redhoop.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/c_sharp.png" class="thumb-img-2 imager" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74"></a>

</li>

<li id="3" style="float: left;">
<a href="https://university.xamarin.com/images/topic-icons/csharp.png" target="myIfOne" onclick="LoadIframeSrc(this.id)" class="thumb-link-4 areffer" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder" id="arefTh3">
<img src="https://university.xamarin.com/images/topic-icons/csharp.png" class="thumb-img-3 imager" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74"></a>

</li>

<li id="4" style="float: left;">
<a href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiFG_7WJ3lSIX3bZ0VqgOavhox1X5CIRc40BJ34C9r9zscCtzd" target="myIfOne" onclick="LoadIframeSrc(this.id)" class="thumb-link-4 areffer" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" data-lightbox="bilder" id="arefTh4" >
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiFG_7WJ3lSIX3bZ0VqgOavhox1X5CIRc40BJ34C9r9zscCtzd" class="thumb-img-4 imager" title="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" alt="50 Speeds Of Play - Gray Steel" height="74" width="74"></a>

</li>


</ul>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>


</div>


<iframe id="ifOne" name="myIfOne" src="" style="display:none">
                
</iframe>
```

I could only manage to get the href on a-tag when I set the target to a iframe that i dont display..Mayby someone else has a better, less sneaky, idea :)